# SharePoint 2010 Approval Work Flow Form - Link to Attachment

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

I have created a custom approval workflow that works as expected. However I am trying to add a link on the approval form to any attachments that were assigned during the creation of the list item.

The steps that I have taken so far:
Added a workflow variable 
Set the workflow variable to the value of the current item attachments
Added a Task Form Field of type string
Set the Task Form Field value to the Value of the Work Flow variable in the Before Task is Assigned Step

There are no errors within the workflow, but when the workflow is initiated (automatic or manual), no task notifications are sent. If I removed the Set Task Form Field value, the workflow will start sending notifications again. I'm assuming it has something to do with how I am trying to build the link to the attachment within the form.

Comment: I think you should give a link to DisplayForm of the list, rather than sending attachment link.. DisplayForm will show the attachments and item details all in one place?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this will need to be done within Visual Studio, so I'm going to give that a try.